# Bluetoothctl connect TIMEOUT exception

Tags: python, bluetooth, connection, pi-zero-w

This is the error I am getting when I connect to my mobile phone using the connect method in this documentation: https://gist.github.com/egorf/66d88056a9d703928f93,

```
raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0xb62e3ab0>
command: /usr/bin/bluetoothctl
args: ['/usr/bin/bluetoothctl']
buffer (last 100 chars): 'mCHG\x1b[0m] Device 98:5F:D3:57:1A:BD RSSI: -47\r\n[\x 1b[0;93mCHG\x1b[0m] Device 98:5F:D3:57:1A:BD TxPower: 4\r\n'
before (last 100 chars): 'mCHG\x1b[0m] Device 98:5F:D3:57:1A:BD RSSI: -47\r\n[\x 1b[0;93mCHG\x1b[0m] Device 98:5F:D3:57:1A:BD TxPower: 4\r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 544
child_fd: 5
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
0: re.compile("Failed to connect")
1: re.compile("Connection successful")
2: EOF
```

The connection is supposed to fail since my phone is connected to another device, however it should return "Failed to connect" and move on to the next paired-device that I have in my loop which calls the connect method. Unfortunately I cannot show my code. What should I do in the connect method to bypass the exception and return false for Failed to connect?

Answer (score 0):

The pexpect library has thrown the `pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT` error which is not caught by the code in `BluetoothCtl`. So you can catch it yourself instead - wrap your call to `connect`, just like the linked gist does for Bluetooth Errors.

import the pexpect exceptions

```
import pexpect.exceptions
```

Add the following method to your calling code and pass it the `BluetoothCtl` object you were using for `connect`. Then you can call this method instead of `connect` to handle the timeout case.

```
def connect2(macAddress, controller):
    try:
        return controller.connect(macAddress)
    except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT:
        print("timed out connecting to {}".format(macAddress))
        return False
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the controller.connect(macAddress) call because the compiler thinks that controller is a String, do I need to pass in a controller object? If so, how?

Comment: your original code i'd imagine would have been something like `controller.connect(macAddress)` instead use `connect2(macAddress, controller)`. I don't know what you called your BluetoothCtl instance though.